# Text missing in taskbar and some windows

Tags: 16.04, xorg, intel-graphics, lxde, text

I'm using Lubuntu 16.04, dist-upgraded from 15.10, on my laptop. With 15.10 I didn't have any problems with the display, but after the upgrade - I started having them. One problem, which I can sort of work around, is the cursor disappearing; switching VTs (Ctrl+Alt+F1, Ctrl+Alt+F7) brings it back. However, sometimes, and gradually, text begins to disappear. That is, some windows, as well as the task bar, lose the text that's supposed to be rendered on them. The rendering does happen, e.g. icons get rendered - but the text is gone. Right now the best I can do is restart X. But I'm guessing I'm not the only one experiencing this and there's something better I can do.

My hardware is a Lenovo X201 with a Core I5 M540 CPU (Intel graphics i915).